# sql server 2008 newsequentialid() problem

Tags: sql-server

I'm having newsequentialid() learning problems in sql server management studio. Create a table with a uniqueidentifier column 'UniqueID', and set the default to newsequentialid().

Step 1. saving the design:

'Table_1' table
- Error validating the default for column 'UniqueID'.

Save it anyway.

Step 2. view the sql:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Table_1](
    [ID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [Name] [nvarchar](50) NOT NULL,
    [UniqueID] [uniqueidentifier] NOT NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]

GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Table_1] ADD  CONSTRAINT [DF_Table_1_UniqueID]  DEFAULT (newsequentialid()) FOR [UniqueID]
GO
```

Looks reasonable.

Step 3. add some rows:

```
1    test    72b48f77-0e26-de11-acd4-001bfc39ff92
2    test2    92f0fc8f-0e26-de11-acd4-001bfc39ff92
3    test3    122aa19b-0e26-de11-acd4-001bfc39ff92
```

They don't look very sequential. ??

Edit: I have gotten it to work somewhat if the inserts are all done at once, then the unique id is sequential. On later inserts, sql server seems to forget the last sequential id, and starts a new sequence.

Running this in ssms results in squential guids:

```
insert into Table_1 (Name) values('test13a');
insert into Table_1 (Name) values('test14a');
insert into Table_1 (Name) values('test15a');
insert into Table_1 (Name) values('test16a');
insert into Table_1 (Name) values('test17a');
```

Comment: Where does newsequentialid() come from?

Comment: It's a bad function name.  The GUIDs aren't sequential, rather they are monotonically increasing.  For this type of guid, 47 bytes are the MAC address,  16 are clock cycle, and 60 bits are the time since 15 October 1582 in 100 nanosecond increments.  If you're curious you can check out Section 4.2 of RFC 4122.

Comment: The values are not sorted on the text representation of the GUID, but on the internal binary value ~ Pro SQL Server 2008 Relational Database Design and Implementation Page 628 Uniqueidentifier

Answer (score 5, accepted):

newsequentialid is primarily to solve the issue of page fragmentation when your table is clustered by a uniqueidentifier. Your table is clustered by an integer column. I set up two test tables, one where the newsequentialid column is the primary key and one where it is not (like yours), and in the primary key the GUIDs were always sequential. In the other, they were not.

I do not know the internals/technical reasons *why* it behaves that way, but it seems clear that newsequentialid() is only truly sequential when your table is clustered by it. Otherwise, it seems to behave similarly to newid() / RowGuid.

Also, I'm curious as to why you would want to use newsequentialid() when you don't have to. It has many downsides which newid() does not, and none of the benefits - the biggest being that newid() is not practically predictable, whereas newsequentialid() is. If you are not worried about fragmentation, what's the point?

Comment: Not 100% like newid(). If several inserts are done at once then the id is sequential.

Comment: @Paul when I try several inserts at once using newsequentialid() on a non-clustered column, the IDs created are the same.

Comment: Even for the clustered index, the newsequentialid() doesn't really 100% follow the "sequantiality" - a few inserting batches might work, but eventually, it'll skip to a new set of GUID's. Try avoiding GUID's - especially as clustered key - by all means!

Comment: @marc_s do you have any documentation on the "sequence" resetting?

Comment: @Rex : i just tried it in two samples - table_1 from above, table_2 with a clustered index on the GUID column - the sequences are *NOT* really consecutive in either case.

Comment: @marc_s The documentation on MSDN states that newsequentialguid() is sequential for that machine, and I've used it reliably in more than one application. I'm curious what other information you have that it may not be as reliable as Microsoft implies?

Comment: I don't know about that - I just tested it. The first couple entries were 00FAF148-1526-DE11-9BA0-005056C00008, 01FAF148-1526-DE11-9BA0-005056C00008 and so forth - nice and consecutive. The third batch I inserted were D0F0AF50-1526-DE11-9BA0-005056C00008 and so on. Definitely not sequential...

Comment: I haven't used it in some time but I remember newsequentialid working pretty reliably in the past... I just google for any other evidence of this "inconsistent" behavior and was not able to find much.  If there are articles or other resources, I'd like to see them please.  Curious.

Answer (score 5):

Those values are actually "sequential" as per [the definition](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189786.aspx) of NEWSEQUENTIALID():

> Creates a GUID that is greater than any GUID previously generated by
>   this function on a specified computer since Windows was started.

It doesn't say there can't be any gaps in the GUIDs, it's just that any new GUID should be greater than the previous one.

Try this:

```
create table #test(id int, txt varchar(50), gid uniqueidentifier)

insert into #test
select 1    ,'test','72b48f77-0e26-de11-acd4-001bfc39ff92'
union select 2,    'test2', '92f0fc8f-0e26-de11-acd4-001bfc39ff92'
union select 3,    'test3', '122aa19b-0e26-de11-acd4-001bfc39ff92'

select * from #test
order by gid asc
```

As you can see, the records are ordered 1, 2, 3 which is as expected.

Answer (score 3):

THEY ARE SEQUENTIAL!

```
1    test     72b48f77-0e26-de11-acd4-001bfc39ff92
2    test2    92f0fc8f-0e26-de11-acd4-001bfc39ff92
3    test3    122aa19b-0e26-de11-acd4-001bfc39ff92
```

77 < 8f < 9b !!! You have to see the highest value byets, not the lowest (from right to left)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with newsequentialid(), for uniqueidentifier types I call newid().

Comment: newsequentialid is provided to solve the problem of page fragementation when clustering on a uniqueidentifier: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189786.aspx

Comment: SQL Server 2008 Books Online  
 
NEWSEQUENTIALID() (Transact-SQL)

Comment: Thanks for the info :). Down vote is a little harsh, though maybe this should have been a comment.

Comment: I didn't think the answer added any value to this particular discussion, but since you made me feel guilty about it I'll pull it back :)

Comment: Wasn't blaming those giving the info. Nor is there any blame, really. Everyone's entitled to their opinion, otherwise, what's the point of having a community?

Comment: Wow, I guess being born a Jew DOES give me the "Guilt Trip" power :P I though it was just a myth!

Answer (score 0):

There definitely can be gaps in `NewSequentialId()` sequences - I've found the following causes gaps:

1. As soon as another call is made by another table needing a NewSequentialId()
2. Failed inserts
3. Rollbacks

(2 and 3 are similar to identity() in this respect)

For example, given 2 tables using `NewSequentialId()`

```
create table XXX(someGuid uniqueidentifier DEFAULT NEWSEQUENTIALID(), x INT)
create table YYY(someGuid uniqueidentifier DEFAULT NEWSEQUENTIALID(), y DateTime)
GO

insert into XXX(x) values(1)
insert into XXX(x) values(2)
insert into XXX(x) values(3)
GO
insert into YYY(y) values(current_timestamp)
insert into YYY(y) values(current_timestamp)
insert into YYY(y) values(current_timestamp)
GO
insert into XXX(x) values(4)
insert into XXX(x) values(5)
insert into XXX(x) values(6)
GO

SELECT * FROM XXX
6A6E85CB-CCA3-E111-9E8E-005056C00008    1
6B6E85CB-CCA3-E111-9E8E-005056C00008    2
6C6E85CB-CCA3-E111-9E8E-005056C00008    3
**CCEA7AF2-CCA3-E111-9E8E-005056C00008  4** Gap here because we 'switched' to y
CDEA7AF2-CCA3-E111-9E8E-005056C00008    5
CEEA7AF2-CCA3-E111-9E8E-005056C00008    6

SELECT * FROM YYY
8F9438E1-CCA3-E111-9E8E-005056C00008    2012-05-22 07:13:35.503
909438E1-CCA3-E111-9E8E-005056C00008    2012-05-22 07:13:41.210
919438E1-CCA3-E111-9E8E-005056C00008    2012-05-22 07:13:41.220
```

Also, NewSequentialId()s aren't returned to the sequence in the case of a failed insert, e.g.

```
insert into XXX(x) values(1)
insert into XXX(x) values(2)
BEGIN TRAN
insert into XXX(x) values(3)
insert into XXX(x) values(4)
ROLLBACK TRAN
insert into XXX(x) values(5)
insert into XXX(x) values(6)
GO

686EFE5B-CDA3-E111-9E8E-005056C00008
696EFE5B-CDA3-E111-9E8E-005056C00008
6C6EFE5B-CDA3-E111-9E8E-005056C00008
6D6EFE5B-CDA3-E111-9E8E-005056C00008

i.e. a Gap of 2 Guids rolled back

and

insert into XXX(x) values(1)
insert into XXX(x) values(2)
insert into XXX(x) values(3)
GO
insert into XXX(x) values(99999999999999) -- overflow
GO
insert into XXX(x) values(4)
insert into XXX(x) values(5)
insert into XXX(x) values(6)
go

select * from xxx
AC613611-CFA3-E111-9E8E-005056C00008    1
AD613611-CFA3-E111-9E8E-005056C00008    2
AE613611-CFA3-E111-9E8E-005056C00008    3
**B0613611-CFA3-E111-9E8E-005056C00008  4** Gap of 1 - overflow failure
B1613611-CFA3-E111-9E8E-005056C00008    5
B2613611-CFA3-E111-9E8E-005056C00008    6
```

Comment: You say "gap" but a gap doesn't necessarily mean it isn't still sequential.

Comment: @Rex M I was being picky. Although new Ids always increase and thus address the fragmentation issue, they are not necessarily consecutive on a per table basis level (like identity). You are mathematically correct in that a sequence doesn't need to be consecutive (or increasing, or unique for that matter), but most readers would associate the word 'sequential' with incremental. I was trying to provide OP with other cases where 'non adjacently consecutive' sequences appear.

Answer (score 0):

NEWSEQUENTIALGUID (as every guid generated in a way that warrant their sequence) includes a part of the Guid calculated via a time stamp. So if you run the inserts at different time you'll see some gaps.

But the important part is that the Guid are "ordered" in a way that do not cause page splits (if the Guid is used in a index) and this is what happens when using the new sequential guid.