# newsequentialid() creating non-sequential IDs when inserts are 8s apart

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, guid, newsequentialid

I'm using SQL Server 15.0.4236.7 and have noticed that GUIDs are consecutive if the row inserts are <8s apart.

Here are some examples:

Inserts were 8s apart:

[image]

Inserts were <8s apart:

[image]

Why is this?

[sql server 2008 newsequentialid() problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/738801/sql-server-2008-newsequentialid-problem) does not answer my question.

The answers there fail to mention why the GUIDs are consecutive in some cases, and non-consecutive in other cases. They only talk about how the GUIDs generated are sequential in that the value increases.

I would like to know why the GUIDs are consecutive when the inserts are within 8s of each other.

Comment: GUID is unique filed. You can't find any GUID with logical order. If you need sequential rows, use identity property in column.

Comment: NEWSEQUENTIALID  -> "Creates a GUID that is greater than any GUID previously generated by this function on a specified computer since Windows was started."  - it guarantees is it greater than, not sequential in the sense of + 1, @Amirhossein
pls read the docs, NEWSEQUENTIALID   has existed for more than a decade:  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/newsequentialid-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16  if you are relying on newsequentialid for anything other than 'comb' indexes, your design is likely wrong.

Comment: @MitchWheat thanks for your comment. It's unfortunate that it has the word "sequential" in the name when in fact, it's not guaranteed to be sequential. Any idea on why the timing between inserts matters?

Comment: Sequential only *really* means that the values follow a logical order, which they *do* @DavidKlempfner ; each value is larger than the last. The values are a sequence, but that are not a **consecutive** sequence.

Comment: As a side note, not even `IDENTITY` or `SEQUENCE` guarantee a consecutive sequence stored within a table; a value by either could be used by a failed `INSERT`, the row could be `DELETE`d from the table, someone might get the next value from the `SEQUENCE` and do *nothing* with it. The only way to guarantee consecutive values in dataset, is to use `ROW_NUMBER` at run time.

Comment: "I want to know why the GUIDs are consecutive when the inserts are within 8s of each other". Because that's how the OS implements `UuidCreateSequential`, the function that `NEWSEQUENTIALID()` is wrapping. If you want more details, break out the assembler and start decompiling, though any conclusions you reach aren't stable across versions. It's not up to SQL Server, in any case (except technically on Linux, since there is no OS function in that case and the compatibility layer/shim implements it itself).

Comment: Looks like the values aren't consecutive at all on Linux (at least in my tests, @JeroenMostert ); at a minimum it increased by a value of 2 GUID values. They were still in sequence though.

Comment: It seems like what you should be asking about here is `UuidCreateSequential` now. The answer to *why* `NEWSEQUENTIALID` only generates a sequential value is because that's also how `UuidCreateSequential` operates. There is no `UuidCreateConsecutiveSequential` nor `NEWCONSECUTIVESEQUENTIALID`.

Comment: @Larnu "The answer to why NEWSEQUENTIALID only generates a sequential value..." - I never asked that question.

Comment: You didn't? So what are you asking then, if it's not about that `NEWSEQUENTIALID` is only sequential and not consecutive.

Comment: @Larnu I'm aware the values are always increasing (sequential), I'm asking why in some cases (ie. inserts <8s apart) the values are consecutive and not consecutive when the inserts are >8s apart. I thought it was obvious based on the two examples I gave in the question.

Comment: Because that's how `UuidCreateSequential` works, which is what the comment you said wasn't applicable tells you... How `UuidCreateSequential` works has nothing to do with SQL Server though.

Comment: @Larnu I'll delete this and ask a new question specifically about UuidCreateSequential